# write record into xml file via simplexml?

Tags: php, xml, file, simplexml

```
$xmldbase = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
$date = date();

$id = (integer) $xmldbase['id'];
$xmldbase['id'] = $id+1;

$xmlString = "
    <player>
        <id>$id</id>
        <name>$name</name>
        <date>$date</date>
        <score>$score</score>
        <right>$rightA</right>
        <false>$falseA</false>
        <ip>$ip</ip>
    </player>";

$xmldbase = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);

$xmldbase->asXML($xmlfile);
```

This works so far but does not add the node player to my file its overwritten. But how I can add my player node? The example does not load a file (https://www.php.net/manual/de/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) where should add the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is similar to:

```
$xmldbase = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile);
$date = date();

$id = (integer) $xmldbase['id'];
$xmldbase['id'] = $id+1;

// add new `player` node to root xml-element
$player = $xmldbase->addChild('player');
// add `id` node to just created `player` node
$player->addChild('id', $id);
// add `name` node to just created `player` node
$player->addChild('name', $name);
// add other nodes here

$xmldbase->asXML($xmlfile);
```

Comment: Feel free to __accept the answer__ and optionally upvote.